# Optional chaining with React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While the optional chaining is a very nice way to avoid throwing errors, is it fine or recommended to be used as part of the useEffect ?

```
useEffect(()=>{
//console.log('Is the Optional chaining fine to use here ?');
}, [objKey?.value])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is generally okay to use optional chaining in a React useEffect dependencies array.

However, it's best to include only the values that are directly relevant to the effect in the dependencies array to avoid unnecessary expressions or computations.